# firefox styling inpu:file. Size attribute doesn't work

Tags: html, css, firefox

I read a lot about styling the input:file for ff, but at least I came with the size solution. However the size is manipulating the textfield of the element and I need to shrink the whole controller, beacause when I put it on size="1" it's too long (only the Browse button). What's the way to shrink it enough (I know css isn't the way to do it)
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [File Style Jquery Plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/filestyle) . So that you can customize it as you wish

Comment: Thanks! I saw the source of this plugin and found out, that it detects only if the browser is mozilla-based (most frequently firefox, but I'm not sure if always) and makes a negative margin-left for the input:file element. I'm doing this with jQuery for now, but is there any way to make a css prefix only for firefox (like _ or # for different versions of IE)?